# Why is the LED not getting turned off?

Tags: arduino, embedded, nrf52832

I have written this code for nRF52832. Shouldn't `LED_1` be turned off when it's executing the `else` branch?

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "nrf_delay.h"
#include "boards.h"
#include "app_util_platform.h"
#include "app_error.h"

#define LED_1       17
#define LED_2       18
#define BUTTON_1    13
#define DEBOUNCE_MS 150

//uint8_t state = 0;

static void gpio_init()
{
    nrf_gpio_cfg_input(BUTTON_1, NRF_GPIO_PIN_PULLUP);
    nrf_gpio_cfg_output(LED_1);
    nrf_gpio_cfg_output(LED_2);
}

/**
 * @brief Function for application main entry.
 */
int main(void)
{
    gpio_init();
    while (true)
    {
       if(!nrf_gpio_pin_read(BUTTON_1))
       {
            nrf_delay_ms(DEBOUNCE_MS);
            if(!nrf_gpio_pin_read(BUTTON_1))
            {
                nrf_gpio_pin_clear(LED_2);
                nrf_delay_ms(100);
                nrf_gpio_pin_toggle(LED_1);
            }
            //state =1;
       }
       else if(nrf_gpio_pin_read(BUTTON_1)) 
       {
            nrf_delay_ms(DEBOUNCE_MS);
            if(nrf_gpio_pin_read(BUTTON_1))
            {
                nrf_gpio_pin_clear(LED_1);
                nrf_delay_ms(100);
                nrf_gpio_pin_toggle(LED_2);
            }
       }
       //if(state)
       //{
       //    nrf_gpio_pin_toggle(LED_1);
       //    state = 0;
       //}
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jag, why are you reading button twice. I think, you must delete second button readings of if conditions. After deleting them, to prevent multiple times reading u must add a while condition into if loops like that "while(condition == 1);", this is the waiting time to release button. I think, you are trying to do that.

Comment: What happens to both LEDs when the button is and isn't pressed?

Comment: Are you sure the SOC is entering the else branch? You could read back what the gpio read function is returning.

Comment: You seem to be using the pin_toggle function as if it performs the opposite function of pin_clear, but it does not. Every time your loop executes, one of your LEDs will toggle (ie change to the opposite state from what is was last). Whether the LED turns on or if when you clear the pin driving it depends on how the LED is connected - if the LED is connected between Vcc and the pin, then clearing it will turn the LED on, not off.

Answer (score 0):

**To read the button** for your application **without error** you can use these code lines, this is the **algorithm** you are trying to do:

```
void main()
{
    initializations();    // Initializations of your program, definings etc.
    
    LED1 = 0;             // LED1 is LOGIC 0.
    LED2 = 0;             // LED2 is LOGIC 0.

    while(1)              // Endless button reading starts.
    {
        if(BUTTON == 1)   // Condition 1.
        {
            LED1 = 1;
            LED2 = 0;
            while(BUTTON == 1);    // Waiting time until LOGIC 0.
        }
        if(BUTTON == 0)   // Condition 2.
        {
            LED1 = 0;
            LED2 = 1;
            while(BUTTON == 0);    // Waiting time until LOGIC 1. 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what the. OP is doing where they read the button twice with a delay between the reads. It's a simplistic attempt at debouncing, and is perfectly adequate in many cases. I do agree with you though that waiting for the button to be released before continuing is often a good idea.